# First load is slow in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Consider my mvc web application startup page having route with parameter:

> Home/Index?Id=123

I am trying to access this with query string.
If I am calling through the below URL

> https://www.xyz.orcg/Home/Index/123

The first load taking too much time(45-50 seconds) and next time it is loading with in 1-2 seconds.

I am having doubts on
1.Hyperlink is loading from WordPress site, so that this issue happened?
2.Once reached this action result,From that parameter, I need to load 4 table data to web page. It is taking for first time around same 40 seconds (total 45 sec) and next time same calls invoking within 1 second

Please help me  out of this issue.

I am using Code First Entity framework,C#,ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity framework very slow to load for first time after every compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423838/entity-framework-very-slow-to-load-for-first-time-after-every-compilation)

Comment: You can use "SQl Profiler", "New Relic" or "miniprofiler" to check what is happening in your application. Normally second time is faster because of caching.