# Send multi ajax at the same time, time response is slowly

Tags: c#, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api

In my current project using ASP.Net vs AngularJs. Now I have a problem about time response of the server. 
When load page I send 2 requests ajax to get data. 
If I send at the same time function `getTopicInfo()` and `getAnswerList()`

```
$scope.init = function (categoryId, topicId, answerId, commentId, userId) {
    $scope.categoryId = categoryId;
    $scope.topicId = topicId;
    $scope.answerId = answerId;
    $scope.commentId = commentId;
    $scope.userId = userId;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;
    $scope.orderBy = getTopicOrderBy();

    getTopicInfo();
    getAnswerList();
}
```

Time response is slowly.

[image]

If I call function `getAnswerList()` after 200ms

```
$scope.init = function (categoryId, topicId, answerId, commentId, userId) {
    $scope.categoryId = categoryId;
    $scope.topicId = topicId;
    $scope.answerId = answerId;
    $scope.commentId = commentId;
    $scope.userId = userId;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;
    $scope.orderBy = getTopicOrderBy();
    getTopicInfo();
    setTimeout(function () {
        getAnswerList()
    }, 200);
}
```

Time response is quick
[image]

I really don't understand. I spend a lot of time on this.

Code of function `getTopicInfo()` and `getAnswerList()`

```
function getTopicInfo() {
    var data = {};
    data.CategoryId = $scope.categoryId;
    data.TopicId = $scope.topicId;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: link("/Topic/GetInfo"),
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            $scope.topicInfo = data.Data.TopicInfo;
            $scope.load += 1;
            $scope.$apply();
            addListener();
        }
    });
}
```

```js
function getAnswerList(page, scroll) {
    page = page || 0;
    scroll = scroll != false ? true : false;
    var data = {};
    data.CategoryId = $scope.categoryId;
    data.TopicId = $scope.topicId;
    if (page == 0) {
        data.CurrentPage = $scope.currentPage;
        data.AnswerId = $scope.answerId;
        data.CommentId = $scope.commentId;
    } else {
        data.CurrentPage = page;
        data.AnswerId = 0;
        data.CommentId = 0;
    }
    data.ItemsPerPage = $scope.itemsPerPage;
    data.OrderBy = $scope.orderBy;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: link("/Answer/GetList"),
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            $scope.answerList = data.Data.AnswerList;
            $scope.currentPage = data.Data.CurrentPage;
            $scope.totalItems = data.Data.TotalItems;
            $scope.load += 1;
            $scope.$apply();
            if (page == 0 && $scope.answerId != 0) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    scrollToId("answer" + $scope.answerId);
                    if ($scope.commentId != 0) {
                        var commentId = $scope.commentId;
                        if (!$("#comment" + commentId).isInViewport()) {
                            scrollToId("comment" + commentId);
                        }
                        $("#comment" + commentId).css("background-color", "orange")
                        $("#comment" + commentId).animate({ 'backgroundColor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' }, 1000);
                    }
                }, 10);
            }
            if (page != 0 && scroll) {
                scrollToId("answers-header");
            }
            addListener();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show the  getTopicInfo();,   getAnswerList() implementation ?

Comment: @user123456 I edited and add code of functions getTopicInfo();, getAnswerList()

Comment: I don't think it has any thing to do with angular, Are you using entityframework?

Comment: Mixing AngularJS and jQuery like this is asking for problems. If you used the $http service instead of $.ajax, you could easily chain the two operations instead of using an arbitrary timeout.

Comment: @Justcode Right. I'm using Entiy Framework.

Comment: I think its moreover entityframework at the first entity framework takes time to cache/compile the table schema. you can try following https://stackoverflow.com/a/30424382/2630817

Comment: @georgeawg Before I try used $http instead of $.ajax but no different.

Comment: @Justcode I try measure time on server. Entiy Framework time excute is quick.
My project structure is as follows
Ajax send request to Controller => Controller send request to Controller API
When slow time spend for Controller API return (end of the line) to Controller is a lot of.

Comment: did you check time by clearing your cache?

Comment: why are you using $ instead of $http?

Comment: @RahulSharma Sometime i need async:false.